# Criar função para testes jest repetitivos

Tags: javascript, testes, testes-automatizados, jest

estou criando testes e2e para as rotas de uma api. Eles precisam ser async, pois consultam direto da api e também na ordem certa, pois algumas rotas precisam de recursos que são criados nos testes anteriores.

Um exemplo de teste que tem em todas as rotas:

```
   it('valida falta de informações', async () => {
      const send: CreateDto = createDto1;
      const response = await request(app.getHttpServer()).post(`/api/${name}`).send(send).auth();

      expect(response.statusCode).toBe(400);
      expect(response.body.message).toEqual(ERROR_MESSAGES);
   });
```

o que muda de rota para rota, é basicamente as variáveis: send (um DTO), name (o nome da rota) e ERROR_MESSAGES.

tentei criar uma função:

```
function postDefaults(name, createDto1, ERROR_MESSAGES) {
   it('valida falta de informações', async () => {
      const send: CreateDto = createDto1;
      const response = await request(app.getHttpServer()).post(`/api/${name}`).send(send).auth();

      expect(response.statusCode).toBe(400);
      expect(response.body.message).toEqual(ERROR_MESSAGES);
   });
}
```

exemplo de uso da função postDefaults:

```
describe("testes do recurso x (e2e)", () => {
postDefalts(foo, bar, foo);

it('outro teste', async () => {
//teste
})
});
```

Porém isso não dá certo. O it('outro teste') é executado antes mesmo da função terminar os testes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para realzar este tipo de testes repetitivos deves utilizar `it.each` (https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testeachtablename-fn-timeout). No caso do teu teste, será algo como:

```js
it.each`
  dto           | routeName     | expected
  ${createDtoA} | ${'route-a'}  | ${ERROR_MESSAGES_A}
  ${createDtoB} | ${'route-b'}  | ${ERROR_MESSAGES_B}
  ${createDtoC} | ${'route-c'}  | ${ERROR_MESSAGES_C}
`(
  'valida falta de informações',
  async ({ dto, routeName, expected }) => {
    const response = await request(app.getHttpServer())
      .post(`/api/${routeName}`)
      .send(dto)
      .auth();

    expect(response.statusCode).toBe(400);
    expect(response.body.message).toEqual(expected);
});
```